# Printing memory addresses in c in visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio

I recently switched from code:blocks to Microsoft visual studio, and I noticed that unlike code:blocks, where every time I declare a pointer and print the memory address, it would save it? It was the same every time no matter how many times I "Build & Ran". But in visual studio when I print, it gives me a new memory address for the same variable every time I compile and run. for ex.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int i;
    int *x = &i;
    printf("%p", x);
}
```

Comment: Maybe your windows box uses ASLR. Does it matter? It shouldn't

Comment: that's how that happens in real life. &i is not guaranteed to be at the same memory location every time you run the program. The fact that it happened with code:blocks is probably a coincidence.

Comment: [ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization) on Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Microsoft_Windows)

Answer (score 2):

Possibly Code::Blocks is not configured to emit position-independent code, while [MSVC, by default, enables `/DYNAMICBASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dynamicbase-use-address-space-layout-randomization).